# Как распарсить полученное от сервера письмо?

Tags: c#, парсер, email, ssl, pop3

Я получил письмо от сервера по протоколу POP3. Письмо пришло в следующем виде:

```
Delivered-To: vasilisa_prek@list.ru
To: vasilisa_prek@list.ru
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 07:32:55 +0300
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: =?UTF-8?B?0JrQvtC80LDQvdC00LAg0J/QvtGH0YLRiyBNYWlsLlJ1?=
<welcome@corp.mail.ru>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?TWFpbC5SdSDigJMg0LHQvtC70YzRiNC1LCDRh9C10Lwg0L/QvtGH0YLQsC4g?=
=?UTF-8?B?0J/QvtC30L3QsNC60L7QvNGM0YLQtdGB0Ywg0YEg0L/RgNC+0LXQutGC0LA=?=
=?UTF-8?B?0LzQuCBNYWlsLlJ1IEdyb3Vw?=
X-MailRu-Host: f373.i.mail.ru
X-MailRu-Hide-Fast-Answer: 1
X-Postmaster-Msgtype: e-mail-ru-welcome
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="------------080400030209020702000207"
```

Как из такого вида грамотно взять тему письма и имя отправителя? Использую язык C#.

Comment: Ключевые слова для гугла - `"C#" mime parser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Mimekit](http://www.mimekit.net):

```
var msg = @"..."; // здесь текст сообщения

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg))) {
    var parser = new MimeParser(stream);
    var headers = parser.ParseHeaders();
    Console.WriteLine(headers[HeaderId.Subject]);
    Console.WriteLine(headers[HeaderId.From]);
}
```

В вашем примере From и Subject содержат несколько строк, по RFC 822 новые строки в заголовках должны начинаться хотя бы с одного пробела, иначе они распарсятся некорректно.